# How to recover a partition recreated with gparted

Tags: partition, data-recovery, software-raid, gparted

Yesterday I've had the bad idea to try to follow this tutorial :

http://fds-team.de/cms/articles/2013-12/use-a-real-windows-7-partition-in-virtualbox-kvm-vmware-player-u.html

these are the commands that I have issued :

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=boot.mbr count=0 seek=2048
sudo apt-get install mdadm
sudo modprobe linear
sudo losetup /dev/loop0 boot.mbr
sudo mdadm --build /dev/md0 --level=linear --raid-devices=2 /dev/loop0   /dev/sdc1
gparted /dev/md0
```

with gparted I have created a new partition table and I have formatted it with the ntfs file system,thinking that I was doing it for /dev/md0 and not for /dev/sdc1. sdc1 is the main partition table where were saved all the most important informations of my life. I don't know where I've wrong but now the partition is empty. What can I do for recover all the informations that there were before ?

Comment: PM 2Ring : I'm trying to use it. Do you want to help me ? what I have to do ?

Comment: Restore from backup...

Comment: Yep; if you don't backup your data, then sooner or later, you will lose it.

Comment: psusi : can you give a look at this tutorial,please ? http://fds-team.de/cms/articles/2013-12/use-a-real-windows-7-partition-in-virtualbox-kvm-vmware-player-u.html I think to have followed the instructions carefully. I didn't understand what's happened...

Comment: he says : The easiest way to recreate the partition table is to create the partitions in the same order as shown in Step 1. Be careful that every number is correct and that there is no difference between the recreated and the original partition table. This is the most critical step in the tutorial and you can easily destroy your NTFS filesystem by doing a mistake here.... yep. that's what's happened to me...

Comment: What happened is you formatted your partition.  You weren't supposed to do that.